# Какое из двух предложений правильнее с точки зрения стилистики?

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

*Во всех его разглагольствованиях ни то что глубокого смысла нет (--) вообще никакого смысла нет.*

*Во всех его разглагольствованиях ни то что глубокого (--) вообще никакого смысла нет.*

Какое из этих предложений лучше стилистически? Какой знак (какие знаки) препинания нужно поставить на месте скобок? В обоих случаях -- тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во всех его разглагольствованиях **не** то что глубокого - (а) вообще никакого смысла нет.

Тире ставится на месте пропуска противительного союза А, частица НЕ пишется при противопоставлении НЕ...А (эта конструкция относится к определениям), повторять слово "нет" не следует.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, второе. Здесь повторение *нет* будет тавтологией, да и звучит некрасиво. Я бы поставил тире, так как *вообще* выделено интонацией.

Обратите внимание: разглагольствовать - разговорное слово, поэтому употребление его в нейтральностилистической речи неуместно.

Comment: В публицистике – вполне нормально.